# msys2 ssh: invalid key format (under Github CI only)

Tags: github-actions, ssh-keys, openssh, msys2

I am cloning [repoB](https://github.com/eudoxos/repoB) within GitHub CI workflow of [repoA](https://github.com/eudoxos/repoA), using deployment key of `repoB` (stored in `repoA`). I understand this might not be a good practice, no need to comment on that (thanks).

[The workflow](https://github.com/eudoxos/repoA/blob/main/.github/workflows/checkout.yml) tests this procedure natively on `ubuntu-20.04` and using MSYS2 on `windows-latest`. It works on Ubuntu, I can run the commands manually on regular MSYS2 installation, but it [fails on GitHub CI](https://github.com/eudoxos/repoA/actions/runs/2228023879). The CI log has all the details, the essential command being

```sh
git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -vvv -i repoB_deployment_key -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' clone -b main git@github.com:eudoxos/repoB.git repoB
```

The failure under Windows is [`Load key "repoB_deployment_key": invalid format`](https://github.com/eudoxos/repoA/runs/6179643748?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:108) and I am not able to find out what's wrong. I tried changing permissions for the private key (`chmod 600`), adding the `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` and `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, running the key through `unix2dos`, adding extra trailing newline — nothing helped.

Again, the same command works under Ubuntu and under MSYS2 on desktop Windows.

The repos are publicly accessible fro reading; you are welcome to open a PR to the `repoA` repository; a PR should trigger the CI run.

Answer (score 1):

Running the key through dos2unix (**not** unix2dos) fixed the issue. I will file that as an issue with msys2, as this should be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your GitHub workflow to display the key first, in order to visually check its content and its format (as [seen here](https://serverfault.com/a/854212/783))

Check also [which SSH you used when creating the key](https://serverfault.com/a/1081949/783), the `c:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64` one, or the one with Git for Windows (`c:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`).

Comment: I figured it out by trial and error - it was `dos2unix` which was needed... ?!